# How to format text partially over image?

Tags: tikz-pic

I have a tall image that I'd like to display along the right hand side of a page, but have text flow along the left side. The image is obviously rectangular in dimensions, but has a large transparent section that I'd like to flow text over.

I've shown this below in the (Visio) picture to show the effect. The shaded area shows the 'interesting' bit of my picture. The lower left is basically white/transparent and I'd like the text to flow over.

Is this possible please?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I would go with an absolute positioned image (using TikZ) + local modification of margin via boxes. However, this would be far from a neat/robust solution!

Comment: thanks ebo - I'm far from a tex/tikz expert. do you perhaps have an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\tikzmark#1{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node[inner sep=0pt](#1){};}


\begin{document}

\leavevmode\unskip\hfill\rlap{\hspace{6mm}\tikzmark{A}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=north east]  at (A) 
    {\includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth,height=0.7\textheight]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage} 

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{0.7\textwidth}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{minipage} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A problem with this solution may be that you need to manually decide which text goes into the first minipage (at the top), and which goes into the second (below). In particular you'll have to handle line-breaks spanning that boundary manually. An alternative solution may be to use `\parshape` for as many lines as are likely to fit at the top.